# Woocommerce follow up email with coupon code after sign up for certain role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently using woocommerce follow up email plugin to provide a coupon code for new user by email immediately after signed up. The problem is, I want the coupon code only for user with 'student' role but the default plugin will send to all users.

Is it possible if I want to show the coupon code section in email only for 'student' role? Can I provide different email content based on role in default wordpress text editor? Because the plugin provide editable template email in default wordpress text editor.

I haven't got much experience with php and WordPress backend environment, Where should I start?

Answer (score -1):

There are many plugins which can do that. You can send emails according to the role.

https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-to-all-registered-users-in-wordpress/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-emails/

These above are free plugins.

For paid, you can visit this: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-emails/13907681?s_rank=7

Comment: Currently I'm using woocommerce follow up email because I want to include auto generate coupon code in email after sign up, but the problem is I want to send the coupon code for certain role only. if I want to show the coupon code section in email only for certain role or send the welcome email with coupon code only for certain role using this plugin?